# The usage of (be something but something)

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I have difficulty understanding this sentence (to be precise, the last clause) in the screenshot below:

[image]

I've tried to use google translate into my native language. If it's in English, I think it's translated like this:

> Paul is optimistic at all.

In relation to the title, does it mean Paul was sanguine? But, I thought **but** in *be something but something* means *except*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Anything but" means not at all, so in other words, "Paul wasn't sanguine (optimistic) at all" (because the prospect of having to learn so many words made him upset).

Here are some more examples of the use of "anything but":

> This website is anything but useless. (= it's useful)
>
> She's anything but ordinary. (= she's extraordinary)
>
> My job is anything but exciting. (= it's dull)